# Moving a created file from template to folder with google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I need help with a google script that I have written which takes the responses from a google form and transfers the responses from the response spreadsheet into a google doc template. The script that I have written now has the proper trigger needed to create the google doc that I want to create but I do not know what needs to be added to have the new document save in a folder that is a created folder in my drive NOT just the my drive folder. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the script I already have written.

---

```
// Get template from Google Docs and name it
var docTemplate = "1NPiAbaB2wciyJUhJE4AvxZ1dCB_Uu5kf24eSxLC_BfI";
var docName = "AttrVaRepairTemp";

// When Form Gets submitted
function onFormSubmit(e) {
//Get information from form and set as variables
var timestamp = e.values[0];
var contact_name = e.values[1];
var company_name = e.values[2];
var phone_number = e.values[3];
var email_address = e.values[4];
var contact_address = e.values[5];
var item_type = e.values[6];
var manufacturer = e.values[7];
var model_number = e.values[8];
var serial_number = e.values[9];
var description = e.values[10];
var symptoms = e.values[11];
var accepted_by = e.values[12];
var warranty = e.values[13];

// Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the Doc’s id
var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
.makeCopy('Repair Form- '+contact_name)
.getId();

// Open the temporary document
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
// Get the document’s body section
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

// Replace place holder keys,in our google doc template
copyBody.replaceText('keytimestamp', timestamp);
copyBody.replaceText('keyacceptedby', accepted_by);
copyBody.replaceText('keycontactname', contact_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keycompanyname', company_name);
copyBody.replaceText('keycontactphone', phone_number);
copyBody.replaceText('keycontactemail', email_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keycontactaddress', contact_address);
copyBody.replaceText('keymanufacturer', manufacturer);
copyBody.replaceText('keymodel', model_number);
copyBody.replaceText('keyserial', serial_number);
copyBody.replaceText('keyitemtype', item_type);
copyBody.replaceText('keywarranty', warranty);
copyBody.replaceText('keydescription', description);
copyBody.replaceText('keysymptoms', symptoms);  

// Save and close the temporary document
copyDoc.saveAndClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

(Copied Serge Insas answer from a similar question elsewhere)

See this old post : (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13532114/google-apps-script-addtofolder-adds-to-folder-and-mydrive/13536275#13536275)

code is as follows :

```
    function moveFromRoot(){
    folder=DocsList.createFolder("MyFolder");
    var file=DocsList.createFile('File2', 'Empty');
    file.addToFolder(folder);
    file.removeFromFolder(DocsList.getRootFolder());
    }
```

but as mentioned in the answer, you can create the file using the folder object itself (folder.createFile('blabla'))